# Make a secure file that PHP can read?

Tags: php, security, file, file-get-contents

I have a file sort of like this, it's a user database (udb.htm):

```
user1:pwd1
user2:pwd2
user3:pwd3
```

something along the lines of that. I would like to secure this file and make it available for PHP via the `file_get_contents("udb.htm");` method, but not a browser window. Thanks!

Comment: Please tell me that you've encrypted the passwords...

Comment: So, you just want to read the file in via PHP?

Comment: You shouldn't use MD5 to encrypt passwords. Really, you shouldn't even store usernames and passwords in a text file.

Comment: Please, don't do this. If what you mean by 'secure this file' is 'stop it from being served to clients', then your users are in trouble.

Comment: You can store usernames, passwords, and salts in a file all you want, provided they're encrypted properly (this is what *nix does). Always assume an attacker exists who has access to all your user data. The trick is in making it virtually impossible to crack the pw/salt combinations.

Answer (score 2):

you can:

- upload the file in a directory outside the public html directory, but that php has access
- block the access to the file using apache .htaccess <Files> or similar
- use HTTP Basic Authentication
- save your data in an actual database (mysql, mssql, oracle, sqlite)

Answer (score 1):

Put the file outside of the web root. For instance, in the directory that contains `public_html`. PHP can access it (and any other file on the system), but you can't get to it from the web.

Answer (score 0):

Move the file into a folder still accesible to PHP but not web clients.

Comment: "move file into folder" - from folder?

Comment: I think the word you're both looking for is 'directory' :D

Comment: @NiallCairns Same thing, doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is put the database below the web path.  So for example, if your website is at www.example.com and it points to:  /var/www/html

Then you can put your password file into /var/www/password/udb.htm

Then access it from your php script as file_get_contents("../../password/udb.htm")

Your script can access the file, but your web service will not.

Answer (score 0):

This changes the permissions of your file before open, and remove grants when you close the file, be sure about webserver permissions over the file.

```
<?php

$file = 'udb.htm';
chmod($file, 0600);
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
chmod($file, 0000);

?>
```

Comment: Wow, I love the answer, but I really think a n00b like me should learn MySQL 0.o